# How to sort footnotes in tables in two columns at the page end?

Tags: tables, footnotes

I have come across a problem and have searched the internet for a solution for two days now, but no luck. I have a couple of tables in my thesis with a lot of footnotes. I have read about the problem with footmarks in tables, so I used to option of savenotes along with the footnotes package to get around this problem. But, since there are so many footnotes in a couple of my tables, it kind of looks weird to arrange them in only one column at the bottem of the page.
So I decided to use two columns by using the dblfnote package. But if I do so the savenotes command is not defined which leads to an error. 
Is there any solution how to handle footmarks in tables and arranging them in two columns at the end of the page?

```
\usepackage{footnote}
\begin{document}
\begin{savenotes}
\begin{table}[H]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{llll}
\toprule
\textbf{1} & \textbf{2} & \textbf{3} & \textbf{4} \\
\midrule
\setlength\extrarowheight{5pt}
a & 12.87 \% & 0.50 \%& 1.21 \%\\
b & 12.14 \% &0.47 \% & 0.58 \%\\
c\footnote{\label{c} footnote } & 0.36 \% & 0.12 \% & 0.03 \% \\
d\footnote{\label{b} footnote d} & 0.35 \%& 0.23 \% & 0.14 \% \\
\addlinespace
\bottomrule
\end{tabular}%
\caption{caption}
\label{tab:test}%
\end{table}%
\end{savenotes}
\end{document}`
```

Comment: Please provide the relevant instructions to transform your code snippets into a compilable LaTeX document. In particular, since you mention a two-column setup, please be sure to indicate which document class and other macros are used to set up the two-column look.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you [indent lines by 4 spaces](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192) or [enclose words in backticks `\``](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863), they'll be marked as code, as can be seen in my edit. You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it). And your example is not a minimal one, and it's not working altogether (no `\documentclass`)

Comment: Hello! Sorry for providing to little information. I am still fairly new to the forum and just looked up how I posted my last question and unfortunately I made the same mistake back then. But I will change that for future questions of course. The problem is, that I use a document class called "thesis" provided by my department at the university. Does the solution depend on the document class? Thank you so much for helping!

Comment: @Nadine Then maybe you should explain which thesis class is that you use. Many universities have their onw, is not a secret. You can find them in the web. If you believe the problem has to do with the documentaclss, let us see which is.

Comment: @Aradnix No it is not that I don't want to share, but I don't know how to and what you would need. You can not find it anywhere online, I know that for a fact, since it is not an official document. I am happy to share it or tell you what ever you want to know. I am such a newbie when it comes down to Latex that I have no idea what you might need and where to find it in the file. I am so sorry.

Comment: @Nadine I understand, anyway would be good can see the code of the `.sty` file you're using. In a faculty of my university was made a class ​​for the thesis precisely. Seeing the code file .sty I saw that it was actually the `book` class but with many restrictions, which IMO is stupid. That `.sty` file was a mess. But I could only know after take a look. I'm not saying the class you use is wrong or a crap, but I think you should let us take a look to see what it does and how and better understand the error you mentioned.

Comment: @Nadine In the other hand, combien tables with footnotes is not as straightforward, involves loading some packages suitable for tables and customize some things in the preamble. Nor is impossible. But creating a complex layout involves an investment of time and effort always.Fortunately there are many questions and brilliant answers about this here. n_n

Comment: The code works fine if I add `\documentclass{article} \usepackage{array,booktabs,dblfnote}` before your code, `\end{document}` after it, and remove `[H]` from `\begin{table}`. If I also add package `float` (or `here`) and put `[H]` back in I can reproduce the issue.